# Converting a String to a Usable Date

Tags: python, json, dataframe, date, datetime

I am in the process of converting a JSON into a dateframe.  One of the items in the JSON is a date in the form of a string.  I am calling the item with the following entry:

`markets_json['events'][i]['periods']['num_0']['cutoff']`

i is a position number in a list that is being generated from a ```for`` loop.  The other fields are dictionary keys.  It returns a string that looks something like this:

`2022-02-19T21:08:00Z`

I would like to turn this into some sort of real usable date that I might even be able to adjust the time zone on.  The best I have been able to do are to use `datetime.datetime.strptime`  or  `parser.isoparse` but those just creates datetime objects (`datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 19, 21, 8, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`) which are not usable to me in the dataframe or I need to know how  make them usable.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by usable? How does your df look like? Could you provide some extra details. Datetime objects should be usuable like that in a df. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: See [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: By usable I meant that I do thing like adjust for the time zone and query off of (date<=...).

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  There were two different time date formats in the JSON.  Some look like `2022-02-19T21:08:00Z` and some are like `2022-02-18 07:38:53.110000+00:00`.  That was causing an issue with the dataframe conversion.  Thank you for your help.